# Converting $r\sin (cx + \alpha) + d$ to a $a \sin x + b \cos x + d$ form

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, relations

All sinusoidal graphs could be represented like this:

$$r\sin(cx + \alpha)+d$$

Where "r" increases the amplitude, "$\alpha$" shifts the function left or right, "c" increases or decreases the period, and "d" increases/decreases the y-intercept.

It is also seen that $r\sin(x + \alpha)$ can be transformed into $a\sin x + b\cos x$, with these relations:

Relation 1: $$r = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

Relation 2: $$cos \alpha = \frac{a}{r}$$

Relation 3: $$sin \alpha = \frac{b}{r}$$

Using this logic, how can you change $r\sin(cx + \alpha)+d$ into a similar cosine and sine function form? What relations would be seen there? If you were to use the same steps as seen with $r\sin(x + \alpha)$, then you would get $\sin cx$ and $\cos cx$ terms. I would like for it to just have $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ terms and the additional "d" value.

Thanks!

**Edit**: You *can* use the same logic (compound angle formulae), but for that you would need to expand $\sin cx$ and $\cos cx$ afterwards.

Comment: $\mathbb R$ represents the entire set of real numbers. You probably should switch it to '$r$', because everyone who reads this question is going to be confused by it.

Comment: Why not use compound angle formulae?

Comment: Yes, but you would end up with $\sin cx$ and $\cos cx$ terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sine function $ f(x)= r\sin(cx + \alpha)+d$ is signal with wavelength ( $x$ is time)

$$ \lambda = \dfrac{2 \pi}{c}$$

Different $c$ frequency waves cannot in general be analytically compounded.

Using Fourier series not in a single but employing an infinite ( finite if frequency is multiple, $c$ is integer ) series  of sine functions $f(x)$ can be summed  up.

To find sum of an odd function

$$ f(x)= \Sigma_{n=1} ^{\infty} b_n \sin nx $$

coefficients of  harmonics are evaluated as

$$ ~~b_n= \frac{1}{\pi}\int f(x) \sin nx ~dx $$

When function is not zero at $x=0,$ even series coefficients $a_n$ should be also bincluded/evaluated.

Comment: So this is representative of all the values of c?

Comment: Yes. Fourier analysis is possible for as long as the waveform is periodic. It need not even be sinusoidal.